# SQL Query with OVER(). Limit output rows with SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

My SQL is quite rusty. I'm using SQL Server Express 2014.
Here's a working query that output a running balance in my transactions table:

```
SELECT Id, AccountId, TrxDate, Amount, SUM(Amount) 
OVER(PARTITION BY ClientId, AccountId ORDER BY TrxDate, Id) AS Balance 
FROM AccountTransaction 
WHERE AccountId=1 ORDER BY TrxDate, ID;
```

This works well to get a valid running balance column. Now, I need to find a way to always count the running balance for the whole table, but only output rows in a date range. If I add a WHERE clause, the OVER() is applied only to the filtered records. So I need a way to execute the OVER() on the whole table, and from these rows, get a subset.

In a stored procedure, is it possible to go through some rows with a cursor, but based on a criteria sent in a parameter (date interval), only output some of the rows?

Is there another way?

Comment: Do you need the running balance for that specific moment, or always for the whole table?

Comment: I don't care about COUNT(*).  I need to filter out the rows. Example:If all the amounts are = 1, my query output rows with balances 1,2,3,4,5, etc.  I want to be able to exclude the first rows, but having the balance column values 3,4,5.

Comment: My running balance is always for the whole table, for a specific AccountId, of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to SO.

The simple way would be a subquery:

```
SELECT * FROM
(
    -- Your query without ORDER BY
    SELECT Id, AccountId, TrxDate, Amount, SUM(Amount) 
    OVER(PARTITION BY ClientId, AccountId ORDER BY TrxDate, Id) AS Balance 
    FROM AccountTransaction 
    WHERE AccountId=1;
)t
WHERE t.TrxDate= @dateparam
```

Comment: Thanks. I get this (truncated) error message: ORDER BY clause is invalid in subqueries,

Comment: oh ok forgot about this, just get rid of order by inside. I'll edit accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a subquery :

```
SELECT Id, AccountId, TrxDate, Amount, 
       SUM(Amount) OVER(PARTITION BY ClientId, AccountId ORDER BY TrxDate, Id) AS Balance,
       (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM AccountTransaction) AS COUNT_OVERALL
FROM AccountTransaction 
WHERE AccountId = 1;
```

You can also use a `APPLY` :

```
SELECT Id, AccountId, TrxDate, Amount, 
       SUM(Amount) OVER(PARTITION BY ClientId, AccountId ORDER BY TrxDate, Id) AS Balance,
       ATT.CNT AS COUNT_OVERALL
FROM AccountTransaction AT CROSS APPLY
    ( SELECT COUNT(*)
      FROM AccountTransaction 
    ) ATT(CNT)
WHERE AT.AccountId = 1;
```

Comment: Rather than add an extra scan, why not just `COUNT(Id) OVER ()`?

Comment: @Larnu. . . `O/P` don't want to count only filtered records, `O/P` want overall count.

Comment: You're right, I interpreted the OP to mean within the account, but it does indeed seem to be for everyone.

Comment: I don't need a COUNT at all. I want the same rows as my original query, but filtered on the TrxDate column. But the OVER() clause needs to apply to all the rows regardless.

Answer (score 0):

USE APPLY

```
SELECT Id, AccountId, TrxDate, Amount, OverallAmount 
    FROM AccountTransaction AT
    CROSS APPLY (
        SELECT SUM(Amount) as OverallAmount 
        FROM AccountTransaction
        WHERE ClientId = AT.ClientID AND AccountID = AT.AccountID AND TrxDate <= AT.TrxDate)
    ) OA
    WHERE TrxDate >= @DateStart AND TxrDate <= @DateEnd
```